# Get instance from a running code in Python?

Tags: python, python-multithreading

I built a code in python with multi classes and threads, after I start the code and because of While True loop, the Code keeps running and writing in each step a Report. I need to link an outside function to the running Code to print the report.

**example :**

*Running code:*

```
import threading as TH
def WriteTXT():
    file = open('File.TXT','a')
    file.write('Test_WriteTXT')
    file.close()
    runLoop()

def runLoop():
    th.start()

th = TH.thread(target = WriteTXT)
th.start()
```

*Outside function :*

```
def report():
    file = open('File.TXT','w')
    Txt_file = file.read()
    print(Txt_file)
```

How to call report function and link it to the Running code to print Txt_file?

Comment: But why you are starting the thread twice?
One in the runLoop and another in the main script?

Would you please illustrate ...

Comment: it's just an example to keep running the code, the main question is how to link an outside function to running code? a function that is not called in the main running code.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

All you would do is call `runLoop()`, `WriteTXT()`, and `report()` functions at the end of the code. You also have to `import` threading "`as`" TH instead of "ad", and add the missing colon (`:`) when defining the `WriteTxt` function. The new code might look like this below:

```py
import threading as TH

def WriteTXT():
    file = open('File.TXT','a')
    file.write('Test_WriteTXT')
    file.close()
    runLoop()

def runLoop():
    th.start()

def report():
    file = open('File.TXT','w')
    Txt_file = file.read()
    print(Txt_file)

WriteTxt()
th = TH.thred(target = WriteTXT)
th.start()
runLoop()
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but I don't need to add report to the example code, report is an outside function. called when I want to get a report from the running code.

Comment: Yeah, let me fix the code.